# How to return an IEnumerable of type X from a method

Tags: c#, linq, oop, types

So what I'm trying to achieve is essentially to pass a type to a method and return an IEnumerable of that type from the method.

This is what I have managed thus far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = PassType(typeof(Test));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> PassType(Type destType)
    {
        var testInstance = new Test() { Name = "Greg", Age = 45, IsSomething = false };
        var destinationList = ((IEnumerable<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { destType }))).ToList();
        destinationList.Add(testInstance);
        return destinationList;
    }
}
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsSomething { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {

    }
}
```

However, this is obviously returning an IEnumerable of type dynamic, I was wondering whether there was a way to return an IEnumerable of type Test

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you use generics? `IEnumerable<Test> x = PassType<Test>();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess OP doesn´t know type at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Actually* what you return *is*  an `IEnumerable<TheType>`, at least at runtime. However you can´t expect the *compiler* to infer type-arguments that you provide att *runtime*. Thus the compiler can´t know of which type the enumerable is, all it knows it that it´s something `dynamic`. This is why you can´t call any members of that type on the instances within the enumeration.

However in your case a simple generic method will do what you want:

```
var x = PassType<Test>();
```

Which needs your method to be similar to this:

```
IEnumerable<T> PassType<T>() { ...}
```

If you don´t know that type at compile-time you may use `MakeGenericMethod` to call the generic method with a type-argument passed at runtime:

```
var theMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("PassType").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Test));
var x = theMethod.Invoke();
```

However during compile-time you still have no knowledge on the type, thus `x` is of type `object`. As `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant since .NET 4.0 you could cast this to `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` if all your types implement `MyBaseClass`. But you´ll never get an `IEnumerable<MyType>` at compile-time and call members of that type directly on the instances.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at Generics in C#.

More info: [**Generics**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: You should consider to write the relevant information from that article to your answer or make this answer a comment.